# Can iOS perform operations when the application is closed in iOS 7 or later?

Tags: ios, background, core-location

For example, find the location and upload it to a server.
I need find the user location when the app is closed and upload it to my server.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done in iOS 6.x and below**

Invoke the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method of the UIApplication class when the app is first backgrounded.

This will grant your app an additional 10 minutes of time
Before that 10 minutes expires, temporarily enable fine-grained location updates using startUpdatingLocation and then request more time using the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method.

The temporary enabling of location updates magically resets the 10 minute background grace period. The app can therefore periodically renew its ‘lease’ before it expires and keep running in the background indefinitely.

below is a detailed walkthrough:

http://gooddevbaddev.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/ios-7-running-location-based-apps-in-the-background/